# not able to register two plugins of touch-ui rte dialog

Tags: aem

I am using the steps given in the URL to make a color-picker rte plugin

http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/01/aem-6-sp1-touchui-richtext-editor-color-picker-plugin.html

and at the same time I am making another custom rte plugin to do some text modulation.

But only one of them is working using rte.coralui2 as categories.
and both icons are coming at the same location.

If I disable one js then another is working.
I have registered the plugin with different name and I have also used different variables.
I am not able to make the rte plugin button at different location.

Please suggest the possible solution.

Comment: Can you provide your code sample?

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for this? me too facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

it's possible you are overlaying rather than extending the rte.coralui2 category. I suspect your custom clientLibs are competing with each other and only one is available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the same steps provided in the blogpost for creating both the plugins and while doing that, you are using the below code twice with different icons :

```
if(items.indexOf(ExperienceAEM.TCP_UI_SETTING) == -1){
    items.splice(3, 0, ExperienceAEM.TCP_UI_SETTING);
}
```

So, maybe, the icons are being added at the same place and only one of them is shown.

You should create ExperienceAEM.CuiToolbarBuilder Class only once and add both icons inside that class